JavaScript Date.getDay() returns the wrong day but only for some users
I'm working on a website for a conference and some users complain that the day of the week in the dates displayed in the schedule is wrong: instead of e.g. "August 3rd (Saturday)" they see "August 3rd (Friday)". August 3rd is a Saturday, so I have no idea how this is possible, it can't be a matter of time zones because the day of the month is still correct.
Here is my function to get the name of the day of a date (the function receives the dates in the YYYY-mm-dd format):
const dayOfWeek = (date) => {
  const dateObj = new Date(date);
  const day = dateObj.getDay();
  const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

  return days[day];
};

(I translated the names of the days in English for your convenience but it's in another language in my code.)
I can't see what's wrong with my code, the only explanation I can find is that getDay() gives different results for different users but I have no idea how this is possible. I can't reproduce the issue, it works correctly for me and other (most?) users, but several users complained about this issue.
Maybe it's a locale issue and for some users the week starts on Monday? But getDay() should always give 0 for Sunday regardless of the locale and the week starts on Monday in my locale too, so I have no idea.
All I could find googling about getDay() giving wrong results was people wanting to use getDate() instead but this is a different issue.
Thanks for your help!

Not sure if it'd help but have you tried getUTCDay()? Sounds like a problem with the timezone on the client side.

Why are you so sure it's not a timezone problem? console.log(new Date('2024-08-03').toString()) prints "Sat Aug 03 2024 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)" when the user uses a central European locale and "Fri Aug 02 2024 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)" when the user uses an eastern locale. As you can see, both users get different weekdays. They also get different days with .getDay(), 5 resp. 6. I guess, you use two different function for your date string. For the date part you use UTC time and for the weekday you use local time.

Damn, you're right, it was a timezone problem. I wrongly thought that new Date() would simply give you the same date regardless of the local timezone, and I used a different function to get "August 3rd" from the date string. getUTCDay() workds, thank you to both of you.

Solved, it was indeed a time zone issue, getUTCDay() instead of getDay() seems to solve it.
